# How do I insert multiple rows with a subquery as one of the value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert multiple rows to a table where the value of one column is from another query. However I got the following error

> more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

How should I do this ?

```
INSERT INTO 
   accounts_account_preferences (account_id, preference_id) 
VALUES 
   ((SELECT account_id 
     FROM accounts_account_preferences 
     WHERE preference_id = 1), 2);
```

Comment: What output do you get when you run `(SELECT account_id FROM accounts_account_preferences WHERE preference_id = 1)` query individually.

Comment: I get a list of account_ids

Comment: That's why you are getting error. The query should return exact one result. Do you want all the account ids to be inserted with preferecen_id set to 2 for all of them? That means you want multiple rows to be inserted?

Comment: You should show sample data..

Comment: yes I want to insert all the returned account_ids with preference_id = 2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `INSERT ... SELECT ...` without `VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO accounts_account_preferences (account_id, preference_id) 
SELECT account_id, 2 
FROM accounts_account_preferences 
WHERE preference_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inner query should return 1 record per outer row. If it returns more than one record then it won't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Explaning why what was attempted failed is OK, but you also need to provide an actual solution to the original question